# Problema al querer actualizar datos en un CRUD

Tags: php

He estado revisando el por un buen rato y la verdad no he encontrado el error, todos los demás módulos si me funcionan pero el de actualizar no me ha querido responder. Lo que pasa es que a la hora de actualizar no se guarda ningún cambio, no me aparece ningún error pero tampoco pasa nada. Quiero pensar que es un error con algún paréntesis o una llave, por que el HTML se ve bien. Espero y me puedan echar la mano.

```
<?php
    include_once 'conexion.php';

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=(int) $_GET['id'];

        $buscar_id=$con->prepare('SELECT * FROM especi WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1');
        $buscar_id->execute(array(
            ':id'=>$id
        ));
        $resultado=$buscar_id->fetch();
    }else{
        header('Location: index.php');
    }


    if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
        $codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
        $estudio=$_POST['estudio'];
        $metodologia=$_POST['metodologia'];
        $muestra=$_POST['muestra'];
        $condiciones=$_POST['condiciones'];
        $interferencias=$_POST['interferencias'];
        $estabilidad=$_POST['estabilidad'];
        $proceso=$_POST['proceso'];
        $precio=$_POST['precio'];
        $lr=$_POST['lr'];
        $id=(int) $_GET['id'];

        if(!empty($codigo) && !empty($estudio) && !empty($metodologia) && !empty($muestra) && !empty($condiciones) ){
            $consulta_update=$con->prepare(' UPDATE especi SET  
            codigo=:codigo,
            estudio=:estudio,
            metodologia=:metodologia,
            muestra=:muestra,
            condiciones=:condiciones,
            interferncias=:interferencias,
            estabilidad=:estabilidad,
            proceso=:proceso,
            precio=:precio,
            lr=:lr
            WHERE id=:id;'
        );
        $consulta_update->execute(array(
            ':codigo' =>$codigo,
            ':estudio' =>$estudio,
            ':metodologia' =>$metodologia,
            ':muestra' =>$muestra,
            ':condiciones' =>$condiciones,
            ':interferencias' =>$interferencias,
            ':estabilidad' =>$estabilidad,
            ':proceso' =>$proceso,
            ':precio' =>$precio,
            ':lr' =>$lr,
            ':id' =>$id
        ));
        header('Location: index.php');
            }else{
            echo "<script> alert('Los campos estan vacios');</script>";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Tienes un *error ortográfico* aquí en la consulta preparada: `interferncias=:interferencias,` creo que lo ves ¿no? De todos modos, no has aplicado la programación *pesimista*, deberías hacerlo.

Comment: A que se refiere con programación pesimista? Y si, ese era el error, gracias.

Comment: Me refiero a que, cuando programas tienes que pensar que TODO puede salir mal y que una de tus tareas fundamentales como programador es dar una respuesta adecuada a cada situación que salga mal. Yo insisto sobre esto, porque generalmente la gente programa de forma optimista. O sea, programan pensando que la vida es color de rosa, que todo irá siempre bien y no, no siempre va bien. Y cuando va mal, el usuario se queda en el limbo, porque no previó. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Sí, se explico muy bien. Gracias por su comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Porque no intentas colocando esto mismo en tu consulta update

```html
codigo=:codigo,
            estudio=:estudio,
            metodologia=:metodologia,
            muestra=:muestra,
            condiciones=:condiciones,
            interferncias=:interferencias,
            estabilidad=:estabilidad,
            proceso=:proceso,
            precio=:precio,
            lr=:lr
            WHERE id=:id;'
```

O eliminar los dos puntos que tienes al comienzo de los nombres de los campos en tu consulta update?, intentalo a ver.